# Where should I define custom methods for entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I created an entity `Post` which has an attribute `body`, this attribute stores markdown (text), I want convert `body` into html (and render it in jsp view) so I added an instance method to the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
  @NotBlank
  private String body

  // ... getters/setters

  public String bodyToHtml() {
    Parser parser = Parser.builder().build();
    Node document = parser.parse(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(body));
    HtmlRenderer renderer = HtmlRenderer.builder().build();

    return renderer.render(document);
  }
}
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="post" items="${posts}">
  <div class="post-body">
    ${post.bodyToHtml()}
  </div>
  <hr>
</c:forEach>
```

I'm wondering is it correct place to define methods like this? What is the best practice in java/spring for such purposes?

Comment: It is not a nice design. I would create a DTO object for `Post` and a service method where the mapping (=html rendering) from entity to DTO is done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DerM, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application so ended up with DTO class `PostDTO` which has all the same attributes as original `Post` and a service `PostService`:

```java
@Service
public class PostService {
  private static final Parser parser = Parser.builder().build();
  private static final HtmlRenderer htmlRenderer = HtmlRenderer.builder().build();

  @Autowired
  ModelMapper modelMapper;

  @Autowired
  PostRepository postRepository;

  public List<PostDTO> getPostsList(int page, int pageSize) {
    Page<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll(
      PageRequest.of(page <= 0 ? 0 : page - 1, pageSize, new Sort(Direction.DESC, "createdAt"))
    );

    return posts.getContent()
      .stream()
      .map(post -> postToDTO(post))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private PostDTO postToDTO(Post post) {
    PostDTO dto = modelMapper.map(post, PostDTO.class);
    Node document = parser.parse(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(post.getBody()));

    dto.setBody(htmlRenderer.render(document));
    return dto;
  }
}
```

Looks much better, thanks for the helpful tip @DerM.